# Native linking error: framework not found for architecture arm64

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.ios, xamarin.ios-binding

I'm binding a Xcode Project like this:

[image]

[image]

Then, I created a static library contains code in `DevQPSDKCore` directory and reference `QPSDKCore.framework`, produces library `libQupaiSDK.a`

Finally, created a new Xamarin binding library

[image]

libQupaiSDK.linkwith.cs

[image]

Run the project get error:

> MTOUCH: error MT5209: Native linking error: framework not found QPSDKCore for architecture arm64
>       MTOUCH: error MT5202: Native linking failed. Please review the build log.

When I remove the `libQupaiSDK.a`, this project run successfully.

I can't get the reason from xamarin logs, any body can help me, thanks.

**Update**:

These two libraries are fat libraries.

```
$ lipo -info libQupaiSDK.a  
Architectures in the fat file: libQupaiSDK.a are: i386 armv7 x86_64 arm64  
$ lipo -info QPSDKCore.a  
Architectures in the fat file: QPSDKCore.a are: armv7 i386 x86_64 arm64
```

Xamarin Studio 6.1.2(build 44)
Xcode 8.1(8B62)

BTW,`-lz` is `dylib` or `tdb` in `Xamarin.iOS` ?

[SDK Source](https://1drv.ms/u/s!AiXQARZGoTx97DVH9G1S5PVkwQky)

Comment: If you run `xcrun -sdk iphoneos lipo -info libQupaiSDK.a`, what is the output?

Comment: @SushiHangover Fat library: Architectures in the fat file: libQupaiSDK.a are: i386 armv7 x86_64 arm64

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The file `libQupaiSDKBinding.a` was compiled referencing `QPSDKCore.framework`, not `QPSDKCore.a` library

[image: .a file references framework]

What you need to do is remove `QPSDKCore.a` file from the binding project and reference `QPSDKCore.framework` correctly (see [topic on embedding frameworks](https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/ios/advanced_topics/embedded_frameworks/)).

Basically, copy over `QPSDKCore.framework` to the `Qupai.iOS` project folder and edit .csproj file adding these lines:

```
  <ItemGroup>
    <NativeReference Include="QPSDKCore.framework">
      <IsCxx>False</IsCxx>
      <Kind>Framework</Kind>
    </NativeReference>
  </ItemGroup>
```

After reloading project you will see your framework as a reference project and you will be able to compile and run the app.

Note the change in .csproj on the left and native reference on the right.

[image: running your app after suggested changes]

Must say the error you had was kind of cryptic and if your post didn't include details about the XCode part, I would not able to find the solution.

Comment: Alex, I have another question, I had binding some frameworks by reference .a directly, and those work well before, why this sdk fail?

Comment: Good question. 
Short answer - no.

This one fails cause you are binding actually a `.a` library X that already references framework Y.  When compiling all this together in a final app, linker can't find framework Y (even though you have a Y-named library).

In your case if you wanted to use the Y framework only (without X library) you could bind it as a framework and as a library. Dependency between X and Y is key here

Comment: I will recheck the framework reference path. Thanks for your detailed explanation. Have a good day. :)

Comment: @AlexSorokoletov Hi Alex,can you please see this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42962939/xamarin-ios-binding-libraries-native-frameworks . Spasibo :)!

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue for MicroBlink library. and the error disappeared after downloading the library again.

Look at this [Link](https://github.com/BlinkID/blinkid-xamarin/issues/5)

This error is related to the fact that there is no framework (binary)
found in the repository.

The repository contains a git submodule to the BlinkID SDK (native).
BlinkID SDK has binary stored on git lfs (large file storage).

So we would recommend the following

1. install git lfs
   `brew install git-lfs`
   `git lfs install`

Note: if you
don't have Homebrew installed, follow the instructions from here:
http://brew.sh

2. clone the repository and use the cloned repo instead of just regular
   download. Clone is important because the repository contains
   submodules.
   `git clone git@github.com:BlinkID/blinkid-xamarin.git`
3. Fetch all submodules

   `cd blinkid-xamarin`
   `git submodule init`
   `git submodule update --recursive`
4. After that, try the BlinkIDiOSBinding project and let us know if it
   works :)